# Expanding a range of regex in sed

Tags: sed, scripting

I have a file with IP address in them that contain regexes on the end.
For example:

```
111.111.11.[2-5]
111.11.11.[2,3,7]
```

And these mean that the IP addresses can be in the ranges 111.111.11.2, 111.111.11.3, etc.

I need to be able to take that file and expand those regexes for each of the options. What I mean by this is given 111.111.11.[2-5], I would run a script on it and get the following results:

```
111.111.11.2
111.111.11.3
111.111.11.4
111.111.11.5
```

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried sed and awk. I was trying to grab the first 3 octets and storing them in a variable and then grab the range and use it in a for loop. The problem i was encountering was that each of these ranges or number of items in a , seperated regex are variable size so I couldn't hard code it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with ***Python*** in such case:

***expand_ip_range.py*** script:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for l in f.read().splitlines():
        # extracting the ending part with a range
        parts = l.rsplit('.', 1)
        r = parts[1].strip('[]')    # getting range relative representation
        if '-' in r:                # if it's range by hyphen `-`
            if r.count('-') > 1:
                raise Exception("Invalid range " + r)
            else:
                bounds = r.split('-') # range boundaries
                for i in range(int(bounds[0]), int(bounds[1])+1):
                    print("%s.%s" % (parts[0], i))
        elif ',' in r:              # if it's range by comma `,`
            items = r.split(',')
            for i in items:
                print("%s.%s" % (parts[0], i))
```

***Usage*** (tested on *Python* 3):

```
python3 expand_ip_range.py yourfile
```

The output:

```
111.111.11.2
111.111.11.3
111.111.11.4
111.111.11.5
111.11.11.2
111.11.11.3
111.11.11.7
```

Comment: This helps a lot! But i only put 2 of the regular expressions on here for an example. There could be any number of regex on the end of the IPs like 111.11.111.[2|88]. Meaning that i could in all possibilities have any variation of regex at the end of the ips